# Drupal Commerce Dynamic Address Field Issue

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've got a problem with the dynamic address field. Maybe it is a problem with the feed-importer, not quite sure about that.

I've imported customers to my database, in the view, name and address are displayed correctly but when i click on edit, those fields are empty. Is there any known issue with feeds-importer and drupal commerce dynamic address fields? Or am I doing wrong?

Or is there a chance to not use the dynamic address field but my own ones? Didn't find anything about that either.

EDIT: everything seems to be fine in the "field_data_commerce_customer_address" database table. Values are added correctly there. Does anyone know which database tables are used in addition to that? Maybe its a database issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that commerce addresses depends on a correctly set country. My addresses did not have one. After adding it, the problem was solved!